# mp4 created by ffmpeg will not play with IPython.display.Video

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, ipython, jupyter

I'm creating a mp4 video from jpegs with ffmpeg, using the following command:

`ffmpeg -y -threads 0 -f image2 -i jpegs/%05d.jpg -framerate 10 video.mp4`

The resulting video will play fine with VLC, but will not play in a Jupyter notebook via:

```py
from IPython.display import Video
Video('video.mp4')
```

This notebook video functionality has worked for me in the past, so I assume there's something about the codec/mime type that the Video function can't resolve?

---

**Requested update**

New command I've tried:

`ffmpeg -y -framerate 10 -i jpegs/%05d.jpg -vf format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart video.mp4`

Video still plays fine in VLC and still does not play in Jupyter. I've looked at the duplicates this is marked as and it does not actually seem to be the same issue..

Here's the output (I've removed the framerate and threads flags to simplify):

```
algo-1-poqk5_1  | 2020-11-18 21:19:36 [INFO]: ffmpeg output:
algo-1-poqk5_1  | 2020-11-18 21:19:36 [INFO]: ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   built with gcc 7.2.0 (crosstool-NG fa8859cb)
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   configuration: --prefix=/opt/conda --cc=/opt/conda/conda-bld/ffmpeg_1531088893642/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc --disable-doc --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-zlib --enable-pic --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-libfreetype --disable-openssl --disable-gnutls --enable-libvpx --enable-pthreads --enable-libopus --enable-postproc --disable-libx264
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
algo-1-poqk5_1  | Input #0, image2, from '/opt/ml/model/outputs/01-IR.mp4_1/%05d.jpg':
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   Duration: 00:00:12.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
algo-1-poqk5_1  |     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
algo-1-poqk5_1  | Stream mapping:
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
algo-1-poqk5_1  | Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
algo-1-poqk5_1  | [swscaler @ 0x55b8cc6fcc40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
algo-1-poqk5_1  | Output #0, mp4, to '/opt/ml/model/outputs/01-IR.mp4_1/video.mp4':
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   Metadata:
algo-1-poqk5_1  |     encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
algo-1-poqk5_1  |     Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
algo-1-poqk5_1  |     Metadata:
algo-1-poqk5_1  |       encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 mpeg4
algo-1-poqk5_1  |     Side data:
algo-1-poqk5_1  |       cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
algo-1-poqk5_1  | frame=   31 fps=0.0 q=31.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:01.20 bitrate=5242.8kbits/s speed=2.33x    
algo-1-poqk5_1  | frame=   64 fps= 63 q=31.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:02.52 bitrate=4161.0kbits/s speed=2.48x    
algo-1-poqk5_1  | frame=   98 fps= 64 q=31.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:03.88 bitrate=3783.5kbits/s speed=2.53x    
algo-1-poqk5_1  | frame=  131 fps= 64 q=31.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:05.20 bitrate=3629.7kbits/s speed=2.55x    
algo-1-poqk5_1  | frame=  164 fps= 64 q=31.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:06.52 bitrate=3216.5kbits/s speed=2.56x    
algo-1-poqk5_1  | frame=  198 fps= 65 q=31.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:07.88 bitrate=3193.6kbits/s speed=2.58x    
algo-1-poqk5_1  | frame=  232 fps= 65 q=31.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:09.24 bitrate=2950.6kbits/s speed= 2.6x    
algo-1-poqk5_1  | frame=  266 fps= 66 q=31.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:10.60 bitrate=2967.7kbits/s speed=2.62x    
algo-1-poqk5_1  | frame=  299 fps= 66 q=31.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:11.92 bitrate=2815.0kbits/s speed=2.62x    
algo-1-poqk5_1  | [mp4 @ 0x55b8cc658900] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
algo-1-poqk5_1  | frame=  300 fps= 65 q=31.0 Lsize=    4202kB time=00:00:11.96 bitrate=2877.9kbits/s speed=2.61x    
algo-1-poqk5_1  | video:4199kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.052020%
```

Comment: Can you try to run it on python 2.7 ?

Comment: I don't think this library is even available for python2 which reached EoL in January

Comment: Okay.. I worked earlier on ffmpeg and I remember there was always an issue with me downgrading with conda environment

Comment: The video plays in VLC, so I think it's just a discrepancy between the default format ffmpeg is outputting and the format the Video function is expecting

Comment: It's the pixel format (it's a common question here). Use `ffmpeg -y -framerate 10 -i jpegs/%05d.jpg -vf format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart video.mp4`

Comment: @llogan This doesn't fix it for me. I also did not have to add these settings in the past to get it working

Comment: @Austin [Edit] your question to show the newest command you tried and the complete log from the command. Possibly a combination of 2 issues (1. bad ffmpeg command, now probably resolved, and 2. something to do with python and/or jupyter)

Comment: Sure. Also to be clear, the video displays fine in VLC

Comment: @llogan are you sure this is a duplicate since the video works in VLC? Also as I mentioned I've created videos with ffmpeg previously that played in jupyter without those flags

Comment: @Austin It's why I asked for additional info. If I believe it is not an issue with ffmpeg, particularly the common pixel format issue, then I'll re-open.

Comment: @llogan sorry it took me a bit, added the output (running using subprocess in python from a docker container)

Comment: I solved the issue. I only needed to add `-vcodec libx264`, which wasn't currently installed in my container.

Comment: @Austin Outputting of MPEG-4 Part 2 video, as confirmed by the log (`mpeg4`), was one of the potential issues I had in mind which is not compatible with HTML5. I will re-open and you can make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
algo-1-poqk5_1  | Stream mapping:
algo-1-poqk5_1  |   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
```

It is encoding to mpeg4. You need a more compatible codec, like h.264